# Glassfish Application specific class loading

Tags: deployment, glassfish, ejb-3.1

I'm trying to deploy an EJB-JAR on Glassfish (4 or 3.1.2.2).
This EJB-JAR has some library dependencies. I would like to deploy these dependencies application specific. No other application running on glassfish should include this specific libraries.

But unfortunately, it doesn't work like described in the following link.
I always get a ClassDefNotFound-Error.

If I copy all libraries in domain-dir/lib/ext, everything works fine. But now, glassfish will include this libraries to ohter applications too. Am I right?

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/gatej.html

Comment: Right, but it's unfortunately difficult to help w/o specifics. You should post the command line, its output and the jar structure for review. You could also try to embed that lib and your ejb into an ear.

Answer (score 0):

Just place the library jar in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your EJB jar. There's no need to setup any additional configuration (like is specified in that link).